# NSbundle pathforresource not finding file

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have images.xcassets listed ounder copy bundle resources, and I did try to just state the file name by itself: MSB_big_icon    , before trying to add the path within images.xcassets.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"/Raymio_android_images/MSB_big_icon.imageset/MSB_big_icon" ofType:@"png"];
NSLog(@"path: %@", path);
MSBIcon *tilecon = [MSBIcon iconWithUIImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path] error:&error];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David Ansermot is right that xcassets is a much better approach and strongly preferred. If you can't use that (running on older versions of iOS for instance), still put everything in one directory and use `imageNamed:`. This has significant caching benefits over hand-loading the file.

An [asset catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1) (xcassets) is a (relatively) new, unified way of managing image resources. The images are no longer accessible as separate files on the disk. Instead, `imageNamed:` consults the asset catalog and fetches the correct asset.

Prior to asset catalogs (and still, for non-images), assets were stored in localized directories. All of your unlocalized assets would be put into a directory called `Resources` (no matter where those files might appear to be in your source tree, and no matter how those files might be arranged in your Xcode folders). Localized files would be stored in directories like `English.lproj` or `French.lproj`. When you make `NSBundle` calls to load `MyImage`, it looks at each localized directory in the order the user has configured, and if it cannot find it in any of those directories, it looks in `Resources`.

Now it is possible to store full directories as "a resource" by marking them as directory references in Xcode. In that case, the whole directory would be copied into `Resources` or the appropriate localized directory. In order to find files inside such a directory you can use the `...inDirectory:` version of the `NSBundle` methods.
So most of the time, you want to just use `imageNamed:`, which is going to fetch things out of the asset catalog if available, and then search localized directories, and then look in `Resources`. If you need to find a non-image, or if for some reason you want the real path to the file, you can compute it like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MSB_big_icon" ofType:@"png"];
```

And if that resource were in a directory tree (because it was a directory reference in Xcode), you can access it like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MSB_big_icon"
                                                 ofType:@"png" 
                                            inDirectory:@"Raymio_android_images/MSB_big_icon.imageset"];
```

Comment: perhaps ill just have to resort to going with the standard, with a nag in the back of my head that I didn't get this to work. Am I wrong in understand that if something is listed under copy bundle resources, that means the listed folder is added to the bundle and can then be used through NSBundle? Because using your last code snippet doesn't work despite images.xcassets being on the copy bundle res. list.

Comment: If you put a file in copy bundle resources, it will be in the root folder. All the subdirectories above it will be stripped away. If you want to keep directories, you have to copy the directory itself (and as I remember, it's been a little while), you have to make the directory a "directory reference" rather than a "folder."

Comment: But why would Xcode bother to already have added files and images.xcassets to copy bundle resources since it is already in the root folder, and on the other hand there are various folders/files in the root folder thats not in copy bundle. From your comment it sounds like copy bundle resource is more when you need to add some folder from outside your apps root folder to the app, right? Either way, Im still a little baffled as to why this approach is still not working.

Comment: @DevilInDisguise I'm not sure what you're seeing. The Copy Files step in your build should generally automatically have all your resources in it. And you should access most of those resources without a directory (because Xcode by default only uses the localization directory structure. It doesn't create any other directories). If your assets are in an xcassets, you definitely wouldn't use the inDirectory example. Just use imageNamed:

Comment: maybe the image.xcassets are the reason I can't use this method? As I mentioned in another comment, I already am using imageNamed, but Im wondering why I can't locate it with imageWithContent.... Thanks for your help anyway

Comment: yes, if you're putting the images in an xcassets, they definitely won't be in a bundle subdirectory.

Comment: even if that xcassets is listed under copy bundle resources?

Comment: correct. that's exactly what it's there for (to bundle the images up so they're not in a directory tree)

Comment: I don't seem to grasp when you're saying that files in copy bundle resources can be accessed by -pathForResource::, and then if its an xcassets listed in the bundle resources they definitely won't be in a bundle subdirectory. Also, since i did mention I was using an xcassets (and you in these comments say its definitely not gonna be in the bundle, maybe change your answer accordingly so I can vote. If the fact is, that I could never access an xcassets by invoking pathForResource. maybe this more suited for a chat, if next comment can end my frustration. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code exemple from one of my apps :

```
NSString *appKey = @"Applications__GENERIC";
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:appKey ofType:@"plist"];
appData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The "Applications__GENERIC.plist" is stored like this :
 
[image]

---

*Other solutions :*
Use the images.xcassets.
Then in your code to load an image, use the code :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImageWithoutExtension"];
```

Don't put any path or extension, only the image's name

Comment: Im interested in the +imageWithContentsOfFile, as that was the method  used in a sample app, hence my wondering as to how it works ( or does not). I did already create some of the images like you posted, but again, Im interested as to why I can't get the above working

Comment: the extension can be added, so no point to suggest that the image's name _must be_ without extension.

Comment: Updated my answer. @holex, if you use xcassets you don't have to. only the image asset name ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MSB_big_icon" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"Raymio_android_images/MSB_big_icon.imageset"];
```

What you can also do to debug is to print out

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleURL]
```

Then navigate to that folder and see if the folder structure corresponds to the path you use.

I just struggled with this today, hope it works out for you too.

Comment: but since images.xcassets is listed under copy bundle resources, I think I would be good started from that location. Meanwhile Im wondering why bundlePath returns the same path as bundleURL, but with a different key